# C# Sending size of object with serialized object over Async socket connection

Tags: c#, serialization, memorystream, asyncsocket, binaryformatter

I want to serialize an object and send it over the network. I have set it up using ISerializeable attribute on my class and BinaryFormatter to convert the object to bytes. I can send the object and deserialize it on the receiving end. However, in order to assure that I have the entire object before trying to reconstruct it, I want to send the size along with the stream. I'd like to set the first few bytes as the size, check when the received data is at least this fixed size, then  I can read that and get the full size of the object. Then, it's simply a matter of waiting until my received data is the size of the object+ the fixed size bytes. How can I offset my data in my stream so that I can send an int to store the size of the object as the first few bytes, and my object as the remaining bytes?

Comment: O please. With your previous question (now deleted) we just established it wasn't the (de)serialization but the I/O.

Comment: I send the data and close the stream. I then read from the stream byte by byte. At any point in the stream, the length is always one byte. I need to be able to send the length to know how long the stream is and to make sure that I am only receiving one object, and not parts of another.

Comment: If your I/O is correct, the Formatter will take care of the length(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer is:

```
SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
socketData.currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
byte[] data = socketData.dataBuffer;
```

Is *not* the right way to read from a SocketPacket

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to prevent? TCP already has built-in consistency and reliability checks.

Comment: My thoughts too... Unless OP is sending over UDP but you wouldn't do that if reliability mattered.

Comment: I want to make sure all of the data is received before creating my object. Since I'm reading the data byte by byte, and I don't know if all of the data has been received without a set size.

Comment: @Chris:  In that case, terminating characters are much easier.

Comment: @Austin @Chris - with terminating characters, you need to parse the data as you go, to ensure that character isn't valid in context, for example as part of a BLOB or Guid. If the intent is merely to *buffer* the data before deserializing, a length-prefix is preferred IMO.

Comment: @Austin could you give me an example. I have a custom object and don't know how to add a terminating character to the stream.

Comment: @Marc basically what I want is a fixed prefix that contains the length. How would I go about adding that to the stream and then reading from an offset, so my object is reconstructing correctly.

Comment: @Chris - you don't *need* to read from an offset; once you have read the (typically 4 bytes) length, it is *gone* - just read the data. Buffering the correct amount of data into a memory stream avoids any over-run issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream();
resultStream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(objectStream.Length));
resultStream.Write(objectStream.ToArray());

// send the resultStream
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you just serialize to a `MemoryStream`, then once that is done add the `.Length` from the `MemoryStream`, followed by the data (use `GetBuffer()` and copy `.Length` bytes from the array). Reverse at the receiver; read the length (typically 4 bytes), then pack that much data into a `MemoeryStream`; rewind the `MemoryStream` (`Position=0`) and deserialize. Of course, you need to agree endianness etc.

(see, and I didn't even mention prot... oh, that other thing)